# PHP - Proper Protocol for storing URLs in $_GET

Tags: php, url, get, store, external-url

What is the proper protocol for storing other websites URL's in your own php page's URL?

For example if I wanted to store `google` it would be easy.

`MySite.com/test.php?url=http://www.google.com`

---

But what about a URL more complex than `http://www.google.com`, like if I wanted to store another website's PHP page.

(e.g. `http://www.AnotherSite.com/page1.php?key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3`)

Then how would I store it in my PHP page's URL? Do you replace all of the "&" symbols with a "\&" phrase? Is there a better method? Does that even work in the first place?

---

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to think about it:

```
$url = 'mysite.com/test.php?' . http_build_query(array(
    'url' => $anything_you_want,
));
```

Otherwise:

```
$url = 'mysite.com/test.php?url=' . urlencode($anything_you_want);
```

You could also use `rawurlencode()`. Notable difference is that it follows [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986).

Further reading:

[`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query)
  [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode)
  [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/rawurlencode)

Comment: I'm not sure who answered first but I enjoyed your further readings! Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Just [encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urlencode) the URLs. You can use the PHP functions `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Just encode it with `urlencode()` if you want to use the entire URL as one parameter:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.AnotherSite.com/page1.php?key=value&key2=value2&key3=value';
echo 'http://MySite.com/test.php?url='.urlencode($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use encoding for the urls.  There are very simple methods built in to PHP to do that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php